# node.js jade - Unable to access nested array elements

Tags: node.js, pug

Sorry if this is a really basic question, but I cannot find any examples similar to the issue I am trying to solve.

Can somebody please explain why I am not able to access a nested array of elements in the following code and also how I can access elements from that array?  From the json below, I am not able to get at the "Items" array found from the second result on.

The following json is being returned:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "...",
                    "type": "..."
                },
                "__index": 1,
                "ID": "someID1",
                "Name": "Some Name 1"
            },
            {
                "__index": 2,
                "Items": [
                    {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "uri": "...",
                            "type": "..."
                        },
                        "ID": "itemID2_1",
                        "Name": "Item 2_1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "__index": 3,
                "Items": [
                    {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "uri": "...",
                            "type": "..."
                        },
                        "ID": "itemID3_1",
                        "Name": "Item 3_1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            ...
```

Here is the jade layout:

```
- var results=records, col_type='even';
table#results(style="border-collapse:collapse;")
  tr
    th.result-header Index
    th.result-header ID
    th.result-header Name
  - each r in results
    - col_type=col_type=='even' ? 'odd' : 'even'
    tr.result-row
      - if (!r.Items)
        td(class='result-col-'+col_type,style="border-left:1px solid black")
          #{r.__index}
        td(class='result-col-'+col_type,style="border-left:1px solid black")
          #{r.ID}
        td(class='result-col-'+col_type,style="border-left:1px solid black")
          #{r.Name}
      - else
        td(class='result-col-'+col_type,style="border-left:1px solid black")
          #{r.__index}
        - each i in r.Items
          td(class='result-col-'+col_type,style="border-left:1px solid black")
            #{i.ID}
          td(class='result-col-'+col_type,style="border-left:1px solid black")
            #{i.Name}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your JSON is in this format

```
{
  "d": { 
     "results": [
        ...
      ]
```

So you need to change this part in your jade template from

```
- each r in results
  - col_type=col_type=='even' ? 'odd' : 'even'
```

to this,

```
- each r in results['d']['results']
  - col_type=col_type=='even' ? 'odd' : 'even'
```

This way, your loop will be pass through each array item.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am actually able to iterate over the result set (i.e., "- var results=records" does the trick).  My issue is that I cannot access the "Items" array.

Comment: Hmmm, I did test this on a local machine. I am able to display all 3 items if I iterate over the results. Fixed a typo in my answer.

Comment: Ah, what does `records` look like? I think you need to `eval()` the returned JSON string first.

Comment: Hi Ace, just to clarify, are you iterating over the results using javascript/jquery or using jade?  Either way, thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah this is using javascript on jade.

Answer (score 0):

so I just ran across the same problem. My solution was to do:

```
- each r in results
  - each i in r.Items
     "... do stuff with i"
```